# Automate script to update csf config

Tags: networking, ssh, mysql

I have this situation:

Port 3306 of MySql is open only to a few IP address than need to connect to mysql directly. This setup I made trought csf config (firewall config of the remote server)

My idea is to close this port in the near future, but for now we need direct mysql connect to this few computer until the provider we work with, upgrade they software to use web services.

This computer im talking about have a dinamic IP address (3rd world internet) and they change almost twice a day. So I made a windows service to alert me via email when the IP changes, and then I connect via ssh to the server and update the csf config file.

Is there any way to update the csf config file automatically? I don't know if it is possible and how to start looking for this. Also , is this idea secure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Register with a dynamic DNS provider, which will give your remote computer a static hostname. Open the file `/etc/csf/csf.dyndns` and add the hostname created (the FQDN). Open the file `/etc/csf/csf.conf` and set `DYNDNS = "300"` (or a suitable value in seconds). Restart the firewall. CSF will use the frequency defined to update the rules to allow whatever IP is found for the hostname you've provided. When the IP changes, your dynamic DNS provider will update its records, your CSF will then update, using the IP the DNS provider has recorded as the latest IP for your computer.

Comment: @Kinnectus I will look into this. And what about security? Is there any way someone "stole" my hostname i register in a dynamic DNS and use his own IP to enter the server? Maybe is a little bit tricky but i always think in this kind of stuff...

Comment: Anyone can lookup a public hostname, but they won't be able to replace the IP it resolves to, that I know of...and, no, no-one will be able to steal your hostname that you register unless they know the account credentials your update client uses to update the DNS provider. The record that gets updated will be an A record because that matches a domain name to an IP. Updating DNS can only be done by logging to a DNS service, making it very difficult to forge the IP address for the hosstname you register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd register with a dynamic DNS provider, such as DynDNS or No-IP, and then configure your firewall (CSF) to use a dynamic DNS (hostname/FQDN) so that it regularly checks what IP the DNS name resolves to and updates its rules accordingly, thus allowing a regularly changing IP to access services unhindered.

Steps from https://help.serversaustralia.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/214714383-How-to-whitelist-a-hostname-in-ConfigServer-Security-and-Firewall-installed-CSF-:

```
1) SSH to the server
2) Open the file "/etc/csf/csf.dyndns" and add the hostname.
3) Open the file "/etc/csf/csf.conf" and set DYNDNS ="300" (which would check for IP updates every 5 minutes). Note: If you want the activity of the IP also ignored, set DYNDNS_IGNORE = "1"
4) Restart the firewall
```